# .Net Framework 4 Client Profile and Windows update default settings

Tags: .net-framework, windows

(Although not a programming question, I ask it here because it seems to be a concern for developers even more than for power users.)

The questions below are actually three questions each one - for win xp, win vista and win 7.

- Does .Net framework 4 client profile is tagged, by default, as a "recommended update" or "optional update" by windows?

  The same question for Win XP Service Pack 3 (which required by .Net 4 client profile).
- Does, by default, windows treats recommended updates as important updates (i.e, download and install both of them as the recommended option?

Comment: As you say, not really a programming question, voting for migration to superuser.com